# How to find the block author in pow substrate chain?

Tags: substrate-node-template, block, proof-of-work

How to find the block author in pow substrate chain?

Answer (score 1):

Integrate this pallet into your runtime.

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/authorship/src/lib.rs

Then you can use `T::FindAuthor::find_author()` to get the block author in code level.

Comment: Actually we are working on pow consensus, so we don't have aura or babe. We are passing default as a block author as you can see here: https://github.com/Polkadot-Blockchain-Academy/Academy-PoW/blob/b522da48f928101c1b05060af7efbbe0c71ccc76/node/src/service.rs#L105C11-L107C1

Comment: How to add actual bock author instead of Default?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look of this implementation: https://github.com/kulupu/kulupu/blob/d9428305d1155514574df79a4692a48711c2bcb2/src/service.rs#L323C1-L324C1

Here in the service.rs we have passed the author by generating miner id in decode_author function: https://github.com/kulupu/kulupu/blob/d9428305d1155514574df79a4692a48711c2bcb2/src/service.rs#L61C1-L107C1